# How to pass password value to wordpress using POST in JSON User API

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, jwt, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to create a registration page using ReactJS and WordPress. to create a user I use a plugin called JSON User API.

Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/

I pass the password using POST request like this

```
https://localhost:8080/api/user/register/?username=test&email=test@test.com&password=test&nonce=0d1faff3b5&insecure=cool
```

it created the user however the password didn't save and I need to manually generate the password on the wordpress dashboard

---

### [wordpress-dashboard-user-setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89D8q.png)

Is there a way to disable the generate password of WordPress or directly save the password to WordPress?

Comment: Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89D8q.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reviewed the API documentation at https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/

It's says for method register you can pass a GET variable 'user_pass'. I included screeshot from source below.

```
https://localhost:8080/api/user/register/?username=test&email=test@test.com&user_pass=test&nonce=0d1faff3b5&insecure=cool
```

[image]

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Comment: Since I took the time to review and help you with a solution, I would kindly appreciate a vote up. Thanks @carljustineoyales